# How to handle tag/class backwards-compatibility in PyYaml?

Tags: python, pyyaml

Let's assume I have a class `MyClass` residing in package `my_package`. Dumping such data to YAML may produce:

```
!!python/object:my_package.MyClass
my_field_1: "foo"
my_field_2: "bar"
```

This data can be deserialized with the default loader just fine. But how can we deal with refactoring the package/class name? For instance, if we rename the package to `my_new_package`, the code fails to deserialized existing YAML files as one would expect:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a Python object
cannot find 'MyClass' in the module 'my_package'
```

How is it possible to add backwards-compatibility to the YAML loader so that loading old data is still possible?

---

My first attempt was to customize the loader and register the old tag name for backwards-compatibility:

```py
class CustomLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    pass

def my_class_loader(loader, node):
    # to be implemented

CustomLoader.add_constructor("!!python/object:my_package.MyClass", my_class_loader)

data = yaml.load(f, Loader=CustomLoader)
```

Unfortunately, PyYaml never calls this custom load. Is there another way to inject the old tag into the loading process?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution, but I'm not sure if that's the most elegant way to solve it:

It looks like PyYaml internally transforms the stored tag `!!python/object:my_package.MyClass` to `tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:my_package.MyClass` before performing the constructor lookup.

Thus, in order to register a custom loader for the old tag name, it's possible to do something like:

```py
# Example class
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(my_field_1, my_field_2):
        self.my_field_1 = my_field_1
        self.my_field_2 = my_field_2

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(d):
        return MyClass(
            my_field_1=d["my_field_1"],
            my_field_2=d["my_field_2"],
        )

# Build a custom loader
class CustomLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    pass

def my_class_loader(loader, node):
    mapping = loader.construct_mapping(node)
    return MyClass.from_dict(mapping)

# Register the old tag name
CustomLoader.add_constructor(
    "tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:my_package.MyClass", 
    my_class_loader)

# Load using custom loader
data = yaml.load(f, Loader=CustomLoader)
```